how to change error (std-err) color
Because standard error is a separate device in UNIX-like environments, and programs or shell scripts can redirect their errors to it, it would be logical to configure terminals (any displayer) to display standard error output in a distinct color.
for example :
error >& 2
standard >& 1
exit 1

For example, in the provided code snippet, both error and standard output will be displayed in the same way on a e.g. terminal. However, the goal is to display standard error (where error is directed) in a different color, without altering the script itself.
also without changing std-err like what happen in stderred project

What do you mean by “without changing std-err”? stderred doesn’t change stderr, it intercepts writes to it. The terminal itself can’t do this, it doesn’t know whether data written to it was intended for stdout or stderr.

It edits text that is sent to the terminal. , It uses ANSI escape codes to make the text red(editing) . It achieves this by using LD_PRELOAD to replace standard functions with its own modified versions , But, if you were right, and the terminal can't distinguish between standard output and standard error, thanks for the clarification! This was what I was looking for.
